# Adding date time to posh-hg prompt

Tags: powershell, mercurial

I have altered my Powershell profile as follows to include datetime in the posh-hg prompt:

```
if(!(Test-Path function:\TabExpansion)) { New-Item function:\Global:TabExpansion -value '' | Out-Null }

# Load posh-hg example profile
. 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Posh-HG\JeremySkinner-posh-hg-e273b0d\profile.example.ps1'

Rename-Item Function:\Prompt PoshHGPrompt -Force
function Prompt() {if(Test-Path Function:\PrePoshHGPrompt){++$global:poshScope; New-Item function:\script:Write-host -value "param([object] `$object, `$backgroundColor, `$foregroundColor, [switch] `$nonewline) " -Force | Out-Null;$private:p = PrePoshHGPrompt; if(--$global:poshScope -eq 0) {Remove-Item function:\Write-Host -Force}}PoshHGPrompt}

$global:HgPromptSettings.BeforeText = " [$(Get-Date -format g)] `n["
```

For some reason the date is not updating at all. I suspect it may have something to do with how posh-hg builds up the prompt, but that's a bit of a wild guess.

Comment: Not a wild guess, it's spot on! :) The `BeforeText` property is a string, so the `$()` subexpression is evaluated *at the time of assignment*, and remains static

Comment: Ok, we'll change _wild_ to _lucky_ ;) So, any ideas how to stick a dynamic date-time string in the middle?

Comment: Put it in the prompt function just before the PoshHGPrompt call :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Currently, there's no way to do what you're trying to do with `BeforeText`.**

If you [look at the code](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/posh-hg/blob/0b86b0dfec088051b3ced22235adb08bf860fe11/HgPrompt.ps1#L4-L10), `BeforeText` is passed into `Write-Prompt` as a string ([L29](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/posh-hg/blob/0b86b0dfec088051b3ced22235adb08bf860fe11/HgPrompt.ps1#L29)):

```
Write-Prompt $s.BeforeText -BackgroundColor $s.BeforeBackgroundColor -ForegroundColor $s.BeforeForegroundColor
```

In order for this to work, the `Write-Prompt` function code would have to be changed:

```
function Write-Prompt($Object, $ForegroundColor, $BackgroundColor = -1) {
    $parameters = @{
        'NoNewLine' = $True;
        'ForegroundColor' = $ForegroundColor;
    }

    if ($Object -is [ScriptBlock]) {
        $parameters.Add('Object', (&$Object))
    } else {
        $parameters.Add('Object', $Object)
    }

    if ($BackgroundColor -ge 0) {
        $parameters.Add('BackgroundColor', $BackgroundColor)
    }

    Write-Host @parameters
}
```

I'm sure there might be a few more changes that would have to be made to make this perfect, but anyway ...

Then, you could set `$global:HgPromptSettings.BeforeText` like this:

```
$global:HgPromptSettings.BeforeText = {" [$(Get-Date -format g)] `n["}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to do the same with `Posh-Git`, and got the same result: Timestamp evaluated once at session start, and being fixed after that.

So I searched the internet, and found this thread about posh-hg and concluded that this has to be true for posh-git as well.

Later the same night, I was reading through post-git issues, and found [this thread](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/501) about adding 'side effects' to the prompt. With my fresh defeat in mind, I added a comment, telling that it might just not work because of the 'evaluated only once'-thing.

But lo-and-behold! Turns out my powershell knowledge is exactly as limited as I was afraid of:

> @rkeithhill: Be careful to use single quotes when supplying the string. If you use double quotes, any variables / subexpressions i.e. $() will only get eval'd once.

So now I have `$global:GitPromptSettings.DefaultPromptPrefix = '$(Get-Date -format HH:mm:ss) '` in my profile, and get timestamps in front of my prompt. Of cause, I have no idea if this works for posh-hg, but at least you could try.